# Child handling SIGQUIT without handler?

Tags: linux, signals

I am learning about signals and what happens to their handlers when a process is forked.  I learned from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31097058/2369597) that "signals have to be installed in the child", and if this does not happen before a signal is sent from the parent, the handler will not be called.  I wanted to find out what this meant, so used strace to see what happens.  Here is my code.  I am not concerned with code critique, unless I am doing something wrong that is causing my problem:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void sighup(int signo) {
    signal(SIGHUP, sighup); /* reset signal */
    printf("CHILD: I have received a SIGHUP\n");
}

void sigint(int signo) {
    signal(SIGINT, sigint); /* reset signal */
    printf("CHILD: I have received a SIGINT\n");
}

void sigquit(int signo) {
    printf("CHILD: I have received a SIGQUIT\n");
    exit(0);
}


int main(void) {

    int pid;
    cout << "Current PID is " << getpid() << endl;
    signal(SIGHUP, sighup); /* set function calls */
    signal(SIGINT, sigint);
    signal(SIGQUIT, sigquit);

    cout << "Waiting to fork..." << endl;
    int x; cin >> x;

    /* get child process */
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (pid == 0) {

        /* child */
        for (;;); /* loop for ever */

    }
    else {

        signal(SIGHUP, SIG_DFL);
        signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
        signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_DFL);

        /* parent */
        /* pid hold id of child */
   sleep(3);
        printf("\nPARENT: sending SIGHUP\n\n");
        kill(pid, SIGHUP);
   int err = errno;
     cout << "sent SIGHUP, err is " << err;
     
        sleep(3); /* pause for 3 secs */
        printf("\nPARENT: sending SIGINT\n\n");
        kill(pid, SIGINT);
   err = errno;
     cout << "sent SIGINT, err is " << err;
     
        sleep(3); /* pause for 3 secs */
        printf("\nPARENT: sending SIGQUIT\n\n");
   
        kill(pid, SIGQUIT);
      err = errno;
     cout << "sent SIGINT, err is " << err;
        sleep(3);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code pauses whilst the users enters an integer after displaying its PID so I can attach to it.  Assuming the parent PID is 11256, child PID is 11313, and that I entered '11' to resume the parent; here is the output from strace:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ sudo strace -f -p 11256
strace: Process 11256 attached
read(0, "11\n", 1024)                   = 3
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fad6078fa10) = 11313
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {SIG_DFL, [HUP], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fad5fe5f4c0}, {0x400bd7, [HUP], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fad5fe5f4c0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [INT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fad5fe5f4c0}, {0x400bfe, [INT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fad5fe5f4c0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_DFL, [QUIT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fad5fe5f4c0}, {0x400c25, [QUIT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fad5fe5f4c0}, 8) = 0
nanosleep({3, 0}, strace: Process 11313 attached
0x7ffe3a8df8a0)       = 0
[pid 11256] write(1, "\nPARENT: sending SIGHUP\n", 24) = 24
[pid 11256] write(1, "\n", 1)           = 1
[pid 11256] kill(11313, SIGHUP)         = 0
[pid 11256] nanosleep({3, 0},  <unfinished ...>
[pid 11313] --- SIGHUP {si_signo=SIGHUP, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=11256, si_uid=1000} ---
[pid 11313] rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {0x400bd7, [HUP], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fad5fe5f4c0}, {0x400bd7, [HUP], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fad5fe5f4c0}, 8) = 0
[pid 11313] write(1, "CHILD: I have received a SIGHUP\n", 32) = 32
[pid 11313] rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})     = 0
[pid 11256] <... nanosleep resumed> 0x7ffe3a8df8a0) = 0
[pid 11256] write(1, "sent SIGHUP, err is 0\nPARENT: se"..., 45) = 45
[pid 11256] write(1, "\n", 1)           = 1
[pid 11256] kill(11313, SIGINT)         = 0
[pid 11256] nanosleep({3, 0},  <unfinished ...>
[pid 11313] --- SIGINT {si_signo=SIGINT, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=11256, si_uid=1000} ---
[pid 11313] rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x400bfe, [INT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fad5fe5f4c0}, {0x400bfe, [INT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fad5fe5f4c0}, 8) = 0
[pid 11313] write(1, "CHILD: I have received a SIGINT\n", 32) = 32
[pid 11313] rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})     = 0
[pid 11256] <... nanosleep resumed> 0x7ffe3a8df8a0) = 0
[pid 11256] write(1, "sent SIGINT, err is 0\nPARENT: se"..., 46) = 46
[pid 11256] write(1, "\n", 1)           = 1
[pid 11256] kill(11313, SIGQUIT)        = 0
[pid 11256] nanosleep({3, 0},  <unfinished ...>
[pid 11313] --- SIGQUIT {si_signo=SIGQUIT, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=11256, si_uid=1000} ---
[pid 11313] write(1, "CHILD: I have received a SIGQUIT"..., 33) = 33
[pid 11313] lseek(0, -1, SEEK_CUR)      = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
[pid 11313] exit_group(0)               = ?
[pid 11313] +++ exited with 0 +++
<... nanosleep resumed> {2, 996222312}) = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (Interrupted by signal)
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=11313, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=894, si_stime=1} ---
restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted nanosleep ...>) = 0
write(1, "sent SIGINT, err is 0", 21)   = 21
lseek(0, -1, SEEK_CUR)                  = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
```

We can see the calls to `rt_sigaction` in the parent to install the SIGHUP, SIGINT and SIGQUIT handlers, and then also in the child for SIGHUP and SIGINT.

**Question 1)** Is this what is meant by "installing" the handlers in the child?  I just assumed (proabably erroneously) that no system calls would be made, and that the child would just be "ready to go" after the fork, without actually re-executing code that was first carried out in the parent.  Was I wrong?

**Question 2)**  I see `rt_sigaction` being called in the child for SIGHUP and SIGINT, but not SIGQUIT.  Yet, the handler for this is still being called in the child (we see "CHILD: I have received a SIGQUIT" being written).  How is the child still handling this signal, when apparently it has not installed the handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this what is meant by "installing" the handlers in the child? I just assumed (proabably erroneously) that no system calls would be made, and that the child would just be "ready to go" after the fork, without actually re-executing code that was first carried out in the parent.

A signal handler is installed by calling `signal` or `sigaction`; on Linux, both of these functions make a `rt_sigaction` system call.

When a process forks, the child simply inherits all of the signal settings from its parent. No code is re-executed.

> I see `rt_sigaction` being called in the child for SIGHUP and SIGINT, but not SIGQUIT. Yet, the handler for this is still being called in the child (we see "CHILD: I have received a SIGQUIT" being written).

Your `sighup` and `sigint` functions call `signal`, which makes a `rt_sigaction` system call to reinstall the handler. Your `sigquit` function, though, just does a `printf` and does not call `signal`.